# loop with while as long as input is digit

Tags: python-3.x

I kinda can't solve this task:

**Create variables**

- int_num and get user input string of only digits
- long_num and initialize it as an empty string

Create a while loop that runs as long as the input is all digits
Inside the while loop

- add int_num to the end of long_num
- get user input for int_num again (inside while loop this time)

**After the loop exits**

- print the value of long_num

*Here's my code:*

```
int_num = input("Enter digit: ")
long_num = ""

while int_num.isdigit() != True:
    int_num + long_num
    int_num = input("You have to enter a DIGIT (integer)!: ")
print(long_num)
```

I need an advice to solve that with only given information from the task.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems but since this is probably homework I don't want to just drop out code.

1) int_num + long_num does an addition but throws away the result, you want to save the result.

2) int_num + long_num is in a place where it will only be done if int_num is NOT a digit.  I think you want to it if it IS a digit.

3) your while loop exits as soon as you get a non-digit.  I don't think that was your intent.

Comment: In an other task i had to send the input from a to b and print b out. can't i do that the same way with int_num & long_num?